# How can I use server-side cursors with django and psycopg2?

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions, psycopg2

I'm trying to use a server-side curser in psycop2 as detailed in [this blog post](http://thebuild.com/blog/2010/12/14/using-server-side-postgresql-cursors-in-django/).  In essence, this is achieved with

```
from django.db import connection

if connection.connection is None:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # This is required to populate the connection object properly

cursor = connection.connection.cursor(name='gigantic_cursor')
```

When I execute the query:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE foreign_id=%s' % (table_name, id))
```

I get a `ProgrammingError`:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't use a named cursor outside of transactions
```

---

I've naively tried to create a transaction using

```
cursor.execute('BEGIN')
```

before executing the `SELECT` statement. However, that results in the same error generated from the `cursor.execute('BEGIN')` line.

I've also tried using

```
cursor.execute('OPEN gigantic_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM %s WHERE foreign_id=%s' % (table_name, id))
```

but I get the same results.

How do I make a transaction in django?

Comment: From the error message it seems your cursor is outside of transactions. Try to use cursors inside transactions.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541937/456550) for an example of how to set it up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you mention in your question but I'll reiterate here for future readers: it's also possible to use explicitly named cursors without bypassing Django's public API:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction

with transaction.atomic(), connection.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("""
        DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT *
        FROM giant_table
    """)
    while True:
        cur.execute("FETCH 1000 FROM mycursor")
        chunk = cur.fetchall()
        if not chunk:
            break
        for row in chunk:
            process_row(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursors should be used inside transactions. You need to define a transaction and to use the cursor inside it.

> -- need to be in a transaction to use cursors.

Taken from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this due to `isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT'` in my `sqlalchemy.create_engine`.