# Django + PostgreSQL Connection - Cannot use server side cursor

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a stored procedure in PostgreSQL that returns a refcursor (its name can be passed as an argument):

```
-- Example stored procedure....
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_stored_procedure(ref refcursor, gid_number integer) RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
ref refcursor;
BEGIN
 OPEN $1 for SELECT * FROM lucca_routes where gid = gid_number;
 RETURN $1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I can get the result set from postgres console with no problems in this way:

```
BEGIN;
select example_stored_procedure('customcursor', 1);
FETCH ALL IN "customcursor";
COMMIT;
```

But, I need to get the result set from inside a Django app (using its postgreSQL connection). According to [this](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors), I tried:

```
from django.db import connections
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def testing_procedure(request):
    connection = connections['default']
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("BEGIN")
        cursor.callproc("example_stored_procedure", ['customcursor', 1])
        # "steal" the cursor - ERROR HERE!
        cursor2 = connection.cursor('customcursor')
        # fetch here the data from cursor2...
        return Response(result)
```

When I try to "steal" the new cursor (cursor2 creation) returned by callproc(), I have the error:

**TypeError: cursor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fetch the data from the refcursor returned by callproc()?

I'm using **psycopg2 2.7.5**

Comment: You could try the `create_cursor()` method ([new in Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#database-backend-api)), which has a name argument. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510593/how-can-i-use-server-side-cursors-with-django-and-psycopg2) might also help.

Comment: Excelent @Alasdair. Using create_cursor() I'm able to use and fetch the data from the server side cursor.

Comment: Glad it worked! It would be good if you add your solution as an answer, to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post the solution for future readers, based on @Alasdair comment.

You can use the function create_cursor(self, name=None) from the DatabaseWrapper object to use a server side cursor.

In my example:

```
def testing_procedure(request):
    connection = connections['default']
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("BEGIN")
        cursor.callproc("example_stored_procedure", ['customcursor', 1])
        cursor2 = connection.create_cursor('customcursor')
        # fetch here the data from cursor2...
        result = cursor2.fetchall() # works!
        return Response(result)
```

Comment: If your database connection has `AUTOCOMMIT=True` and you want a ["without hold" server-side cursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors), you have to do this inside a `transaction.atomic()` block. [Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7f19e3713598a37b0809b5434114140170d12e34/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py#L224)